# functional automation of Metro, iOS apps ----- UI object identification techniques

Tags: java, javascript, ios, windows, automation

Folks - I am looking for an automation tool to automate windows 8 metro application and an iOS application for functional automation

I have researched some tools and found about 
Ranorex UI automation tool (for metro and iOS applications)
UI automation (by Microsoft)  (for metro apps)
UI Instruments (for iOS application)

The real problem I am facing is with all these UI automation tools, if there is a small change in the UI, the scripts are failing ......

I want to test the functionality first and need more robust scripts/tools to handle UI changes.
How can I identify metro app objects uniquely? I see that the UI code is XAML

Also, I have the source code of the app available and don't mind using variables or resources from it in my automation code....

Can anyone please suggest any good tools or How I can handle this?

My manager wants a real customer experience !! **Also, would be great if scripting can be done using Java, Javascript**

**No record and playblack tools which identify based on the static text please !!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unfortunately one of the pit falls of front end automation.  The reality is a small change can make a very large impact on your automated scripts.  This is why most people suggest that you do not spend an inordinate amount of time on the front end and stick to unit/integration tests, and only automate ui functionality if you have no other choice.

I can't speak as to UI automation, or UI Instruments, but as far as Ranorex is concerned to make a more robust test the key is the xPath that Ranorex uses to track your elements.  The obvious answer is to track on the objects unique id, but this isn't always feasible.  What you can do is find an object above it that will be there, for instance instead of finding a specific table element, find the table, and programmatically create the adapters for the element on that table, then find the element you are looking for from one of it's properties, inner text/tag value/any available property.  You will still run into situations where a ui change will cause script failures, that is unfortunately part of the process of front end automation.

I don't personally recommend using your source code for your front end testing, it can cause unrealistic scenarios that can actually cause more problems than they actually help find.  The true answer here is to think of your front end automation as a last resort for testing, and if you can test something in another way to use that other way.